# Trying to get an Android app on the emulator

Tags: android, http, android-emulator

I am trying to develop an Android app that can connect to the Internet and read data from the website specified. However, when I run the program on the emulator nothing happens. Can someone please help guide me on what I need to do? Here is my code

```
public class HttpExaplme extends Activity {
TextView httpStuff;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_http);
    GetHttpEx test = new GetHttpEx();
    String returned;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class GetHttpEx {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.mybringback.com");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l ="";
        String nl= System.getProperty("line sperator");
        while((l = in.readLine())!=null)
        {
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
                return data;
       }
    finally
    {
        try{
            if(in != null)
                {
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From a command prompt (and assuming you have your PATH), run the following command to view your logs (and see your error): adb logcat

Comment: From honeycomb version of android it has been made compulsorily . UI thread work on complsory on UI thread and Non-UI thread work on Non UI Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're crashing because you're doing HTTP requests on your UI thread.  That isn't allowed-  you'd make your app unresponsive, so it throws an exception.  All HTTP requests must be made in a thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: In addition to this, if you're simply debugging and testing a bit you can turn this check off simply by turning down the targetSdk in your manifest.xml, as older versions don't do this check. You should ofcourse never actually launch an app like this though.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the emulator has connectivity to http://www.mybringback.com. Do this by opening this site in the android browser. Corporate firewalls may block the emulator requests by default.

Second, as @Gabe said, wrap your network requests in a AsyncTask. Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Get back here after these steps. Please post a stacktrace. You can view it in logcat (adb -e logcat on the command line).

HTH

EDIT: Have you set android.permission.INTERNET in your manifest?